# Spring profile XML bean configuration required to be at beginning of file

Tags: spring

Using the below Spring configuration I load `com.Test2` when DEV profile is used and load `com.Test1` when in all other cases:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="bean1"
              class="com.Test1">
    </bean>

    <beans profile="DEV">

    <bean id="bean1"
          class="com.Test2">
    </bean>

    </beans>
    
</beans>
```

Moving the Spring profile configuration to the beginning of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <beans profile="DEV">

    <bean id="bean1"
          class="com.Test1">
    </bean>

    </beans>

    <bean id="bean1"
          class="com.Test2">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

the IntelliJ IDE reports the error:

```
Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean}'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
```

Why is this error reported ? Why is it required that the Spring profile be set at the beginning of the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is reported because, according to the [XML schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd), in the second case the elements are in the incorrect order:

[image]

As you can see, any `<bean>` declaration must be provided before any nested `<beans>`.

This restriction is also indicated in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-xml):

> It is also possible to avoid that split and nest `<beans/>` elements within the same file, as the following example shows:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="...">

    <!-- other bean definitions -->

    <beans profile="development">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql"/>
            <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql"/>
        </jdbc:embedded-database>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="production">
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource"/>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

> The `spring-bean.xsd` has been constrained to allow such elements only as the last ones in the file. This should help provide flexibility without incurring clutter in the XML files.

Comment: @blue-sky Does the answer make sense to you?

Comment: You are welcome @blue-sky. It was also curious to me when I first realized it on a project. I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful.

Comment: if your interested I've posted a similar question to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65775753/which-bean-is-loaded-if-profile-is-not-set :)

Comment: Yes, of course, I will follow the question.